# Cannot execute Javascript from Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

In the past it has been possible to write JS in the Chrome console (and is still possible on Firefox).  However for the last month or so this hasn't worked, anything I type in there is silently accepted with no obvious impact, functions I call are clearly not run, etc.  See this screenshot where even a direct console.log() fails to produce output:

[image: Console not running command]

I can't find any documentation indicating the feature was removed nor can I find any obvious causes for why this isn't working anymore.  This is happening in Chrome 52.

Comment: Might be a configuration issue, I can run console.log() on the latest Chrome build (which is 53, but also worked on 52) and it outputs two lines as expected, one for the log and another for the void return value.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm suspecting, but I'd love to know _what_ setting caused this since I didn't really mess with anything out of the box.  Hard to find any useful documentation since this feature doesn't really have a distinct name to search for.

Comment: After clicking on console, make sure you have either `all` or `logs` selected, to view the `console.log()` outputs

Comment: @devights Other possible situation is when you override `console.log` defaults. Something like: `var console = {}; console.log = function() {};`

Comment: Try disabling extensions to see if any of them are interfering. There's a useful extension called "Disable Extensions Temporarily" that provides a 1-click way to disable all extensions (except itself, of course).

Comment: Disabling all extensions didn't work.  I didn't override console.log and that was only an example, I can't execute any JS from the console.

Comment: Strange problem, but is likely not programming related and may be better served by asking on [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

The little icon next to the no smoking looking sign that looks like a half of an hour glass (see image), click on it. This is the filter settings.

[image: filter]

Step 2:

It will give you this option:

[image: console]

Click on the `logs` or `all` tab to show console logs.

Comment: I just tested this. It filters the messages that are output with `console.log()`, but it doesn't filter the `undefined` line that shows the return value of the call. So it wouldn't explain his symptom.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not resolve it, both 'all' or 'logs' continue to show no output.